# SQL Server allow viewing of jobs by job category

Tags: sql-server-2017, sql-server-agent, jobs

I know how to assign or create "categories" for jobs.  But is there a way to actually view jobs by category by default.  I do not want to see all the jobs just listed within SQL Server Agent.  I'd like to be able to have a view where I expand "SQL Server Agent" and I first see all the categories and I can expand each category to see the SQL job.  Is this possible?

**I already know I can right click the jobs folders and do "Manage Categories" and view jobs by category there, but that is not what I am looking for. I am looking for a default view to show jobs by category.**

Comment: What you are asking is not possible. You should create an SP with categories as input parameter and then use it to view the data from msdb.

Comment: @KinShah - Thats a shame considering you cannot create folders to store jobs in.  The purpose of categories is pointless to say the least.

Comment: Open a connect item and lets see if MS will address this or not :-) Good luck !

Comment: @KinShah - No thanks - I used to do that with SSRS and I got nowhere.  It is what it is but it seems this is something that would make sense to organize and group jobs.

Comment: If it's too much effort to create a feature request in Connect (now in Azure), you can vote this one up. It's close to what you want. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32900965-ssms-add-ability-to-filter-jobs-by-category

Comment: Does the ability to sort by Category in the Job Activity Monitor get close to what you want?

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to do a join between [msdb].[dbo].[syscategories] and [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs]

Here is the job view [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs_view] and the column [category_id] will give you the number used to find category

```
SELECT sjc.name
 , suser_sname( j.owner_sid )
 , j.name
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs J
LEFT JOIN dbo.syscategories sjc ON j.category_id = sjc.category_id
WHERE sjc.name = 'category'
```

Comment: This is not what I am asking - please re-read the question.  I want this directly in SSMS not as a query to run.